# Options for research opportunity

Tags: phd, job, collaboration, internship

**BACKGROUND**

I am working as a faculty member in the CS department of engineering university of a South Asian country for the last couple of years. I have done my masters from another  Asian country. My main activities are teaching only. I do like teaching but I like doing research projects more. Unfortunately, here, I do not get enough time to work on projects due to already teaching responsibilities and secondly, there is no research group or such environment in my department that works in the same field as I want to do.. i.e. Data Science, Applied Machine Learning. Also, here, there aren't any positions for researchers explicitly. In short, I do not have a research environment and collaborators around.

Nevertheless, I want to advance my research career and get involved in a good research project long-term or short-term. In my opinion, I have the following options:

1. PhD
2. Research stay
3. Research internship

**PROBLEM**

I have been applying for Ph.D. positions abroad (and still have been), mainly Europe but I'm quite open to NZ/Aus, Canada/US. However, until now I have not been able to secure any. For research internships and research stays, 1) its really hard to find because many groups don't mention 2) I have contacted to some and they said they do not have the funding or open positions. 
Well, the time is ticking and after not getting positive enough response over time, I contacted some and asked if I can come on self-funding. But, since I am from the EU, and for Visa, the universities need at least official funding source and not some personal funds and for countries like Germany, they require me to fixed deposit funds for the entire 2 years before they give me a visa.

I do not find enough time to work on a decent project and publish papers myself while doing a full-time job of teaching. With every day passing, I am not getting younger.

**MY QUESTION**

So, what other options could I look into to get an opportunity to work on a research project? and strengthen my profile so that I could get a fully funded Ph.D. position or a position of a researcher.I do not have an official funding source. nor too much funding to pay tuition fees of the institute but have enough that I can survive in another country or even work part-time.  
I am not a really dumb guy. I really want to do some quality research having some real impact. It is just that I do not have such a top-quality research profile that is required to get funded positions or researcher jobs (at least that's why my experience of getting rejections).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will need to make time or reorganise your teaching somehow. Also, consider making your teaching and pedagogy the focus of your research. Your teaching would be a good platform to examine and investigate educational approach and innovation in your field. Unfortunately, without evidence of research that is relevant to potential employers, you are going to be left further and further behind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are only one who answer unlike other 48 people. Neverthless, what you said, is what I am already doing. I came here for help and suggestion. Guess, I won't get any here as well.

Comment: Are you doing research in your pedagogy and publishing? It does not sound like you are publishing at the moment. Also are you able to create time now so you can do the research projects that you want to do? You will need to take steps to change your circumstances. If you don't have enough time then I don't think any answers here can help you create time as you are in a full time teaching position. You need to develop expertise. You need expertise to be competitive in order to do "quality research with some real impact".